# Converting octal to decimal with an 8 in the question

Tags: computer-science, computational-mathematics

I was given (2228)8 to convert into decimal, I came up with:

```
(2)8³ + (2)8² + (2)8¹ + (8)8⁰
```

However i know 8 and 9 aren't used in octal so im left not really knowing what to do. Any help would be appreciated on how to solve a problem like this

Comment: $(2228)_8$ doesn't really make sense; shouldn't it be $(2230)_8$? So it'd be $2\times 8^3+2\times 8^2+3\times 8$ originally?

Comment: @Dave Thank you! Your comment was right, it should be rewritten as (2230)8.